# Integrate YAF.NET in my existing ASP.NET WebForm project

Tags: asp.net, integration, yaf

Ok so I have a website and I want to integrate it with [YAF.NET](http://www.yetanotherforum.net/), I'd like YAF.NET to use the same Membership Provider as my web application already does, and I was wondering what would be the best way to achieve this result.

I have both the webapp and YAF working perfectly fine on their own.

I thought maybe the best way was using a virtual directory, but then I wouldn't be able to use a master page file from the webapp within YAF. And just copying and pasting the whole project sounds horrible. Maybe I should just paste the DLLs and try figuring out what's left but there's a lot of stuff like services and I'm not sure whether they'd work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet Another Forum.NET uses standard ASP.NET Membership defined in the web.config.

Change the membership provider in web.config file.

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms"/>
  <membership
  defaultProvider="myMembershipProvider" >
    <providers>
      <add name="myMembershipProvider"
      type="myMembershipProvider"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
      connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.
        OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\myMembershipProvider\
        App_Data\Members.mdb;Persist Security
        Info=False"
        />
    </providers>
  </membership>
</system.web>
```